# JSON_QUERY with Column values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

One of my tables contains JSON values in each row of a column.

The data is as below (example. one row)

```
[{"id":"30a66bec-c0aa-4655-a8ef-506e52bfcc14","type":"nps","value":"promoter","decimalValue":"10"},{"id":"37850b3b-1eac-4921-ae22-b2f6d2450897","type":"sentiment","value":"positive","decimalValue":"0.990000009536743"}]
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve two columns from it. (id, value)

I'm writing the below query using `JSON_VALUE` but getting `NULL` values in each row of the new column.

```
select a.jsondata,JSON_VALUE(a.jsondata,'$.id') from table as a
```

Comment: you have an array, so you need to consider it with your select

Comment: Hi @nbk I actually have never worked with JSON. So could you help me with the query.

Comment: there are many threads about array json and jsON_VaLue, i wonder why you didn't find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON field is an array so you need to specify which element you're after, assuming its always the first you can use:

```sql
select a.jsondata,JSON_VALUE(a.jsondata,'$[0].id') from table as a
```

You need to change the index inside the square brackets to access the id you want from the JSON string

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON array. If you want to break it into multiple rows you need to use `OPENJSON`

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (t.Json)
  WITH (
    id uniqueidentifier,
    value varchar(100)
  ) j;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e98110dcf1a6e439372dfe548d0d8a0f)